# Can we use Paypal Express Checkout with “Ship to multiple address” option

Tags: magento-enterprise, paypal

We are using Paypal express Checkout using onepage checkout option in Magento. Its working fine and now, I am trying to use the same inside "Ship to multiple address" option.

Based upon my research, I am not sure whether it is possible or not.

So, My question is - Can we use Paypal Express checkout in case of Multishipping option?

I tried to enable (by setting the below data member to True)

```
protected $_canUseForMultishipping      = false;
```

in Payment method model class which result in display of the payment method in the payment section but never redirected to Paypal window instead displayed error on clicking place order:

```
PayPal gateway has rejected request. Invalid token (#10410: Invalid token).
```

Any quick help would be highly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Magento's integration with PayPal's Express Checkout does not support multiple shipping addresses. Based on PayPal's documentation, Express Checkout *seems* like it supports multiple addresses (in the form of multiple authorizations), but Magento's integration doesn't utilize that functionality.

We can confirm this by looking at `Mage_Paypal_Model_Express::authorize()`, which calls `Mage_Paypal_Model_Express::_placeOrder()`:

```
if ($order->getIsVirtual()) {
    $api->setAddress($order->getBillingAddress())->setSuppressShipping(true);
} else {
    $api->setAddress($order->getShippingAddress());
    $api->setBillingAddress($order->getBillingAddress());
}
```

Note how the payment method only provides a single shipping address to the API model (the API model then does the actual PayPal API call).

Comment: Thanks for the help..Do you know any URL either on Paypal or Magento website that can verify this fact?

Comment: I can't find any page that explicitly says this, but I added a code-based explanation to my answer.